# Baud Rate instable on RPI4

Tags: raspberrypi, serial-port, cpufreq

I have a strange problem. I'm running a TCP to Serial server I wrote in Python3. It uses the UART of the RPI4 at 500000 baud. Initially I wrote it for a NanoPi and runs fine, but when switching to the RPI4 I had comm errors. I attached a oscilloscope to the TX and saw that when commands failed the baud rate was lower. While investigating I could relate it to the clock speed on the RPI4. watchcat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq shows 600000 when it works fine on the first command then the CPU freq goes to 1500000. Then I see the baud rate change. When switching back it works again. I fixed the CPU speed now to the low freq with echo "powersave" |sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor. Then it keeps running. But the RPI runs half speed of course. When I fix the CPU freq to "performance" I keep having the same problem with changing baud rates even though the CPU freq stays at 1500000. I'm very puzzled about all this. Anyone any suggestions?

Comment: how does this relate to ask ubuntu?

Comment: I tough it was stable, but when I use another USB Serial it also switches baud rate??

Comment: Because I forget to say I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on it

Answer (score 1):

I actually fixed it myself. Disabling bluetooth fixed the problem. Not it is stable and it doesn't matter which governance mode I run. Here is what I did:

I added dtoverlay=disable-bt in /boot/firmware/config.txt